# Webpack wont bundle an npm module generated with wasm-bindgen

Tags: webpack, wasm-bindgen

I wrote a little library in rust for doing some computation with complex numbers. I generated a wasm bin and js shim with wasm-bindgen cli, published it, and tried to use it in a little react app. For the life of me, I can't get webpack to bundle this thing.

I have an asynchronous split point and am trying to use wasm-loader I'm getting "magic header not detected" from webpack with this configuration. I've also tried not specifying a loader in which case I get at error: "module parse failed: Unexpected section at 0x83" and it tells me I may need an appropriate loader for this. I'm unsure what a magic header is supposed to be or what other loaders to look into.

Here is my package.json and webpack config:

```
{
  "name": "julia-set",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "complex-julia-funcs": "^0.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "preset-react": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "volleyball": "^1.5.1",
    "wasm-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

and the js code calling the npm module:

```
const numberReader = async () => {
  const { ComplexSqr } = await import("../../node_modules/complex-julia-funcs");
  const z = new ComplexSqr(2, 3);
  console.log(z);
};

export default numberReader;
```

The npm module is https://www.npmjs.com/package/complex-julia-funcs

Comment: Hey, so I turned up this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6725#issuecomment-391237775

adding
'''type: "javascript/auto"'''
did work for webpack but now react is complaining about regeneratorRuntime, not being defined which i think can maybe be fixed (with polyfill?). will update as I carry on tinkering

Comment: Polyfill did indeed work